# The page you requested was not found codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have setup the codeigniter, default controller is working(welcome.php) but when i add new controller its not working

Default controller :

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function testing()
    {
        $this->load->view('test');
    }
}
```

**http://localhost/appointment/index.php/welcome/     (working)**

New controller

```
class democontroller extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('test');
    }

}
```

**http://localhost/appointment/index.php/democontroller/     (not working)**

Comment: `democontroller` spelling should be `Democontroller` and file name `Democontroller.php`

Comment: thank you it worked

Comment: read this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 2):

Change the following code:

```
class democontroller extends CI_Controller {

}
```

to

```
class Democontroller extends CI_Controller {

}
```

and save this file with name `Democontroller.php` and try again.

**Note: controller name first character must be capital as per naming convention.**